# bootstrap modal issues with jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a link when clicked upon opens up a bootstrap modal with a form :

```
<a href="#number_form_1" role="button" data-toggle="modal" style='color:white' id="schedule">Click To Fill</a>
```

The issue is i want to trigger the modal via Jquery and not like this . So when i change the above link to a button as below :

```
<button id="form1" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Click To Fill</button>
```

And user jquery inside document.ready as below :

```
$("#form1").click(function(){

            $('#number_form_1').modal('show');
        });
```

The popup does not work . I have tried everything possible to figure out the issue but it just doesnt work . I have even alerted something after `$("#form1").click(function(){` and it worked but the modal doesnt .

Please advice .

Answer (score 2):

1. remove `data-toggle="modal"` from button
2. use your modal's id instead of using button's id in `$('#myModal').modal('show');` , here myModal is modal's id.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('button').click(function(){
$('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

[DEMO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tvshajeer/hLxauuaz/)

Comment: This is exactly what i am doing ,but it doesnt happen at all . But for some reason it works if i use the link directly . <a href="#number_form_1" role="button" data-toggle="modal" style='color:white' id="schedule">Click To Fill</a>

Comment: @user1411837  did you try this? `$('#number_form_1').modal('show');`
you have given button id here. and remove that `data-toggle="modal"` from your button.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put the form inside the modal then call it like this in Jquery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#form1").click(function () {
    $('#myModal').modal({
        show: true
    });
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            .....
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="form1" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Click To Fill</button>
```

Comment: Did you change the ids?

Comment: Yes i did . The form is inside the modal and only works if i use the link like this :
<a href="#number_form_1" role="button" data-toggle="modal" style='color:white' id="schedule">Click To Fill</a>

Comment: Since you're using bootstrap, you can use `class="btn btn-default" role="button"` in your link. Refer to this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/mattmorz/59251fc8/2/